# Regex for any character that is not alphanumeric, whitespace, or a doublequote

Tags: neovim, regular-expression, search, substitute

I expect this to select all non-alphanumeric characters:

```
[^\w]
```

Instead it selects all non-w's.

This is the regex I would use in JavaScript, Python etc.:

```
[^\w\s"]
```

How can I write this so that it's compatible with vim?

Comment: Hang on, don't you want simply `\W`? Edit: Oh, nevermind, you could not use that with other classes in a bracket expression.

Comment: @Quasímodo yeah it would be a little verbose (`\W\|\S\|[^"]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[..]` form is known as a collection (`:h /[]`) and can contain a sequence of characters and/or one or more ranges of characters, separated with `-`. It will match any single character that is contained in the sequence/range(s). You can, of course, also match the inverse with `^`.

In `:h white-space` you'll find a collection equivalent to `\w`:

```
\w  word character:         [0-9A-Za-z_]
```

So one approach is to invert/negate that equivalent:

```
[^0-9A-Za-z_]
```

Alternatively, collections can also contain the "character classes" found under `:h E944`. These are the same character classes that have been around forever in the BRE/ERE patterns used by legacy tools and POSIX environments.

Alphanumeric chars have the following character class equivalent:

```
[:alnum:]   isalnum ASCII letters and digits
```

You can invert/negate that like so:

```
[^[:alnum:]]
```

(You could also probably use negative lookarounds with `\w` but that's *relatively* difficult compared to this straightforward analog to `[^\w]`.)

**Update:** I just realized I didn't address the full pattern you posted. Just look for a character class that's equivalent to `\s` and you'll find `[:space:]`. And `"` is just `"`. So `[^\w\s"]` becomes:

```
[^[:alnum:][:space:]"]
```

One other thing, this is likely to be the most performant of any possible solutions since others have lookarounds or alternations (`|`) and those are expensive.

Comment: Is `[:alnum:]` etc NeoVim only as in vim 8.0.586 `/[:alnum:]` highlights some alphabetic c characters, not all , and no digits `/[:digit:]` highlights different alphabetic  characters and no numeric characters at all

Comment: `[:alnum:]` will highlight `a`, `l`, `n`, `u`, `m` and `:`. You want `[[:alnum:]]`. Character classes must be in a collection.

Comment: @B Layer  Thanks. That helps a lot.